# Reading Python implementations

Tags: python, python-2.7

Curious about how Python's `itertools.product` was implemented, I took to searching the C:\Python27 directory. Could not find it. This lead me to post these related questions:

I understand that the statement `import xyzabc` reads a module from some place (possibly where the environment variable directs it), but since I found no module `itertools`, 1) how is it being imported? and 2) can someone point me to that implementation? (or is it written is C, so that I will have trouble reading it?)

Mildly related: 3) is anything Python "closed source"?

Comment: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l1984

Comment: fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `itertools` module is one of the modules compiled directly into the interpreter;  see [`sys.builtin_module_names`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names) for a full list of these modules.
2. The itertools module is implemented in C, see e.g. its [Python 2.7 source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c).
3. No, all of the CPython implementation is open.